# Reuse deleted ID field in MSSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Suppose I've an ID column in database:

[image]

I want to delete row number 3:

[image]

Now Id's in my database are following:

[image]

**Question:** Is it possible to reuse (in this case) ID 3 field. So ID 4 jumps to ID 3 field? So database should be like that:

[image]

I also know about RESEED command `DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, RESEED, desiredIDNumber)`, but I don't think that I need this in my case. Becase ALL ID's from (in my case) 2> will change. (ID3 gets ID4, and ID4 gets ID5. ID5 does not exists anymore).

Comment: Why do you think you have to do such a thing???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking if there is a magical command to do this?  Not that I have ever heard of. *{Frankly I have never heard anyone even want to do this before}*

Are you asking if this is technically possible?  Sure.  It would be a major undertaking.  You could write a program that does this but the overhead of all that work to change all of the foreign key references would be pretty massive which leads to ...

Why?  What are you expecting to get out of this?  "Empty" space does not hurt.  Did you run out of space in the integer field?

Answer (score 1):

The general idea would be: `UPDATE T SET ID = ID - 1 WHERE ID > 3`

You can customize this to your liking. Probably you need to enable identity insert for this statement.

Be careful because this might cause corruption if other data references these IDs. IDs are generally not supposed to change. Maybe you rather add a new column `ContiguousID INT NOT NULL` and let the `IDENTITY` value alone.

Answer (score 0):

If the Id column is an *identity* column, you cannot get Sql Server to fill in the missing IDs as part of it's automatic increment process. It won't do it.

You can fill in the ID yourself, by using the [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221.aspx) command.

Generally, it's not worth the trouble.